# Adding coupon discounted price to woo-commerce product page

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hello I am looking to show a coupon discounted price on a woo-commerce product pages. I found code that is written for woo-commerce 3.x but that is pretty outdated and we are running the latest release 6.9.1. The code for 3.x is below. Any help would be fantastic.

with this code it returns this error

syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file

```
if ( WC()->cart->has_discount() ) {
        $values = array (
            'data'      => $product,
            'quantity'  => 1
        );
        $coupons = WC()->cart->get_coupons();
        $_price = $product->get_price();
        $undiscounted_price = $_price;
        if ( ! empty( $coupons ) ) {
            foreach ( $coupons as $code => $coupon ) {
                if ( $coupon->is_valid() && ( $coupon->is_valid_for_product( $product, $values ) || $coupon->is_valid_for_cart() ) ) {
                    $discount_amount = $coupon->get_discount_amount( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_discounts_sequentially', 'no' ) ? $_price : $undiscounted_price, $values, true );
                    $discount_amount = min( $_price, $discount_amount );
                    $_price          = max( $_price - $discount_amount, 0 );
                }
                if ( 0 >= $_price ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( ( $product->get_price() > 0 ) && ( $undiscounted_price !== $_price ) )
                $price = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $undiscounted_price ) ), $_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: The code is incomplete, please update your question and provide the correct & complete code.

Comment: Ive added everything I have.

Comment: Sorry to say, it's still not complete. this code should be wrapped in a function and that function should be attached with a filter hook.